# Makefile expanding variable inside define

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
define func1
    include $(shell pwd)/test/$(strip $1)/component.mk
    $(info :::::::${NAME} ::::::::::::::: )
endef

INCLUDES := a  b c

$(foreach dir, $(INCLUDES), $(eval $(call func1, $(dir)) ))

all : $(objs)
```

Contents of each makefile:

```
cat test/a/component.mk
    NAME := AA

cat test/b/component.mk
    NAME := BB

cat test/c/component.mk
    NAME := CC
```

Output is

```
::::::: ::::::::::::::: 
:::::::AA ::::::::::::::: 
:::::::BB :::::::::::::::
```

It looks like first time NAME is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the expansion of `$(foreach dir, ${INCLUDES}, $(eval $(call func1, ${dir}) ))` in painful detail.

- `${INCLUDES}` is expanded, giving `$(foreach dir,a b c,$(eval $(call func1,${dir})))`
- Next `dir` is set to `a`
- `$(call func1,a)` is expanded

  - `1` is set to `a`
  - `func1` is expanded:
    `include $(shell pwd)/test/$(strip $1)/component.mk`
    `$(info :::::::${NAME} ::::::::::::::: )`

    - `$(shell pwd)` becomes `HERE`, say (N.B. Use `${CURDIR}` instead)
    - `$(strip $1)` becomes `$(strip a)` becomes `a`
    - `${NAME}` expands to nothing
    - `$(info ::::::: ::::::::::::::: )` expands to nothing

      - As a side effect `::::::: :::::::::::::::` appears on *stdout*
- `$(eval $(call func1,a))` expands to `$(eval include HERE/test/a/component.mk)`, expands to nothing

  - As a side effect, the *include* is processed by *make*
  - Presumably `HERE/test/a/component.mk` exists and contains valid *make* syntax,
    and the variable `NAME` gets a value.

`1` is set to `b`. Lather, rinse, repeat.

## Tip

To get a hint of problems in code like this, always run *make* with `--warn`:

```
$ make --warn -Rr
Makefile:8: warning: undefined variable 'NAME'
::::::: :::::::::::::::
⋮
```

## Fix

To get some insight, replace the `$(eval stuff)` with `$(error [stuff])`

```
$ make
::::::: :::::::::::::::
Makefile:8: *** [    include /cygdrive/c/Users/somewhere/a/component.mk
    ].  Stop.
```

Here we see the `$(info …)` has disappeared even before it has got to the eval.
The naive fix is pretty horrible.

```
define func1
  include $(shell pwd)/test/$(strip $1)/component.mk
  $$(info :::::::$${NAME} ::::::::::::::: )
endef
```

Running this with the `$(error …)` in place gives

```
$ make
Makefile:8: *** [    include /cygdrive/c/Users/somewhere/a/component.mk
    $(info :::::::${NAME} ::::::::::::::: )].  Stop.
```

That stuff between the `[` and `]` is valid *make* syntax.
Tidied up it looks like:

```
include /cygdrive/c/Users/somewhere/a/component.mk
$(info :::::::${NAME} ::::::::::::::: )
```

Job done. There are cleaner ways, but you need to understand the pain first!